# Cannot find Google Apps Script written before Google Workspace Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, add-on

I wrote an extension for Google Docs that used to show up in the Add Ons menu for my organization.  The add on no longer shows up in the menu, but I can see it in the Google Workspace Market.  I originally had it on the Google Chrome Webstore, but then it moved to the Workspace Marketplace.  I can also see the corresponding project in my Google Cloud Platform console.

However, when I go to the Google Apps Script Editor, my project is not there.  I have no access to the source code or ability to fix it so that it will show up in the Add Ons menu again.  Does anyone know where I might be able to find script?  I have the URLs for the Workspace Market, but it is private to my organization, so no one will be able to view it.

Also, I tried going through Google Support but they said that App Scripts is not supported and to ask on Stack Overflow.

Edit:
Screenshot of error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Answer to [rev 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69812850/1)

Open the Google Marketplace SD settings page on the Google Cloud project linked of your add-on. There you should find the script project id.

Then on your web browser open your Google Apps Script project by writing a URL like this:

`https://script.google.com/d/<<put-here-the-script-project-id>>/edit`

If the above doesn't work, see notes at the bottom

## Resources

- [Publish an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview)
- [Enable and configure the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk)

### Related

- [How can I view the source of a google apps script Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31993969/1595451)
- [Library with identifier underscoreGS is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65575459/1595451)

## NOTES

If you get the message "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time", try again using Chrome on incognito mode with all the extensions disabled and signing in only with an account that has access to the Google Apps Script project.

If the above doesn't work either, follow the screen advice, wait a bit and try later.

### Related

- [Google Drive Page Not Found - Sorry, unable to open the file at this time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47045209/1595451)

Comment: I found the script ID in the Google Marketplace SDK page (MEp8Hhiuw7BGULDY693z3FYf4jNky_38D) - How do I use this to find the script in the script editor?

Comment: @MitchMK Answer updated

Comment: Thanks so much - however it is still not working.  That URL is giving a 400 error.  I do notice that the script ID from GCP is only 33 characters long, while the ones in the Script Editor all seem to be 57 characters long.

Comment: @MitchMK I'm sorry... bad URL pattern. I updated the answer (tested with an add-on that I published on Chrome Web Store)

Comment: So that got me a new error page, which seems slightly promising - I edited the question to insert the screenshot

Comment: @MitchMK  The "orthodoxic" way to proceed is to post a new question mentioning that you tried the URL suggested in my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that - still new to posting to StackOverflow.  Alas, I tried in Chrome, only logged in to one account, with extensions off and I get the same page

Comment: Maybe the project is not shared with the account that you are trying to use.

Comment: It is the account I created it with, and the one which has access to the GCP project - is there anyway to set the account access through GCP?

Comment: @MitchMK Not directly. For stand alone project the access to Apps Script project are managed from Google Drive  or https://script.google.com and for bounded projects from the container file (spreadsheet, document, presentation or form)